# Displaying an excel table into PyQt gui window

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt4

I need bit of assistance with my python code. I am a newbie to python so not very good at it.
I have an excel spreadsheet with a bunch of lecture times and I am using the code below;

```
df = pd.read_excel('/home/pi/timetable1.xlsx')
df['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Date']).dt.strftime("%d-%m-%Y")
now = pd.to_datetime('today').strftime("%d-%m-%Y")
print(df[df['Date'] == now])
```

which displays a simple line of timetable text such as below [xx:xx is time in 24 hr format];

```
Lesson 1:  Lesson 2:  Lesson 3:  Lession 4:  Lesson 5:
xx:xx      xx:xx      xx:xx      xx:xx       xx:xx
```

I have configured it so that the above displayed times only shows the times for the "Current Date".
What I am trying to acheive is that I want to use PyQt4 to display this information on a graphical window.

So for example, the below displays "HELLO WORLD" text in the gui window;

```
def wxfinished():
    attribution3.setText("HELLO WORLD")

attribution3 = QtGui.QLabel(foreGround) 
attribution3.setObjectName("attribution3")
attribution3.setStyleSheet("#attribution3 { " +
                           "background-color: transparent; color: " +
                           Config.textcolor +
                           "; font-size: " +
                           str(int(50 * xscale)) + #50 is the size of the text
                           "px; " +
                           Config.fontattr +
                           "}")
attribution3.setAlignment(Qt.AlignTop)
attribution3.setGeometry(450 * xscale, 670 * yscale, 1000 * xscale, 1000)

w.show()
w.showFullScreen()

sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

How can I change it so that instead of "HELLO WORLD" I can print out the timetable output?

Answer (score 2):

While I'm not that familiar with Pandas, here's an MRE to help you. In this, a table is made, the labels are set to the excel's labels (lesson x), and the singular row is filled out with the dates.

```
from PyQt4.QtGui import QApplication, QTableWidget, QLabel, QFont
from PyQt4.QtCore import Qt
import sys
import pandas

CELL_FONT = QFont()
CELL_FONT.setPointSize(8)

def getLessions(): # assuming the code you provided works
    """
    Returns Pandas DataFrame object w/ today's date info
    :return:
    """
    data = pandas.read_excel("path")
    date = pandas.to_datatime(data["Date"]).dtftime("%d-%m-%Y")
    now = pandas.to_datetime('today').strftime("%d-%m-%Y")
    return data[date == now]

def makeWidget():
    datum = getLessions()
    columns = len(datum.columns)

    # Use table to display information
    table = QTableWidget()
    table.setRowCount(1)
    table.setColumnCount(columns)

    table.setHorizontalHeaderLabels(datum.columns) # I think datum.columns returns [str], I could be wrong
    table.setVerticalHeaderLabels([""])

    # Row will be filled with Labels w/ times
    for i in range(columns):
        lession_time = str(datum.iloc[0,i])   # edit: iloc returns a Timestamp object

        label = QLabel()
        label.setFont(CELL_FONT)
        label.setText(lession_time)
        label.setAlignment(Qt.AlignHCenter | Qt.AlignBottom)
        table.setCellWidget(0, i, label)

    return table

def makeWidgetDummy(): # Doesn't use Pandas
    columns = 5

    table = QTableWidget()
    table.setRowCount(1)
    table.setColumnCount(columns)

    horizontal_lbls = ["Lesson {}".format(i + 1) for i in range(columns)]
    table.setHorizontalHeaderLabels(horizontal_lbls)
    table.setVerticalHeaderLabels([""])

    for i in range(columns):
        lession_time = "XX:XX"

        label = QLabel()
        label.setFont(CELL_FONT)
        label.setText(lession_time)
        label.setAlignment(Qt.AlignHCenter | Qt.AlignBottom)
        table.setCellWidget(0, i, label)

def main():
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    widget = makeWidget()
    # widget = makeWidgetDummy()
    widget.show()
    app.exec_()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Comment: Thanks for youre reply. I tried the above and I receive the following error;                                                   line 1348, in makeWidget
    label.setText(lession_time)
TypeError: setText(self, str): argument 1 has unexpected type 'Timestamp'
Segmentation fault

Comment: You can cast lession_time as a string and that should fix it. I thought iloc[0,i] would access an integer or string, not an object. Pandas should have a string representation for their Timestamp class